# count field database by group

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, count

table
order

```
id_order | date    | id_product | id_size | id_gender | name |
   1     |2012-1-1 |     1      |    1    |    1      | john |
   2     |2012-1-1 |     1      |    2    |    1      | mayer|
   3     |2012-1-1 |     2      |    1    |    1      | chris|
```

tabel product

```
id_shirt |  name   |
   1     |  jeans  |
   2     |  shirt  |
   3     |  jacket |
```

tabel size

```
id_size  |  size  |
   1     |   S    |
   2     |   M    |
   3     |   L    |
   4     |   XL   |
```

i would produce like this where gender male.

```
name  |  S  |  M  |  L  |  XL  |
jeans |  2  |     |     |      |
shirt |     |  1  |     |      |
```

Please query in codeigniter code .

Comment: @user1682073: Please *edit* the *question* to include your code.

Comment: jeans should have `1 in S`, and `1 in M` not `2 in S`

Comment: You need to define whitch value that represent male and female in the example only a 1 is shown and what is that male or female?

Comment: @MattiasJosefsson: Apparently male, judging by the names and requested output.

Comment: So its certain that 0 is female then?

Comment: The value for female, or any other genders, shouldn't matter, considering it appears to be a foreign key to a 'genders' table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) S,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) M,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) L,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'XL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) XL
FROM    orderTB a
        INNER JOIN productTB b
            ON a.id_product = b.id_shirt
        INNER JOIN sizeTB c
            ON a.id_size = c.id_size
GROUP BY b.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df10d/2)

Alternatively, If you have unknown values of sizes, a *Dynamic SQL* is much more preferred, eg

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = ''',
      size,
      ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ',
      size
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM sizeTB;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  b.name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM    orderTB a
                          INNER JOIN productTB b
                              ON a.id_product = b.id_shirt
                          INNER JOIN sizeTB c
                              ON a.id_size = c.id_size
                  GROUP BY b.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df10d/6)

Comment: + `INNER JOIN genderTB g ON g.id_gender = c.id_ender WHERE g.gender='male'`